# Why does Java WeakReference case OutOfMemoryError？

Tags: java

I know Weak reference will be easy to GC. and

> Weak reference objects, which do not prevent their referents from being made finalizable, finalized, and then reclaimed. Weak references are most often used to implement canonicalizing mappings.
> Suppose that the garbage collector determines at a certain point in time that an object is weakly reachable. At that time it will atomically clear all weak references to that object and all weak references to any other weakly-reachable objects from which that object is reachable through a chain of strong and soft references. At the same time it will declare all of the formerly weakly-reachable objects to be finalizable. At the same time or at some later time it will enqueue those newly-cleared weak references that are registered with reference queues.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html

But， the follow code will case OOM。

```
//-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx20m -Xms20m -XX:+PrintGCDetails
@Test(expected = OutOfMemoryError.class)
public void testOne() {
    WeakReference<List<char[]>> holder = new WeakReference<>(Lists.newLinkedList());

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        holder.get().add(new char[_512_KB]);
        System.out.println("i = " + i + "; size = " + holder.get().size());
    }
}
```

the print info is

```
> [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 5632K->496K(6144K)] 5632K->1184K(19968K), 0.0022957 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
i = 0; size = 1
i = 1; size = 2
i = 2; size = 3
i = 3; size = 4
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 5497K->496K(6144K)] 6185K->5477K(19968K), 0.0027950 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
i = 4; size = 5
i = 5; size = 6
i = 6; size = 7
i = 7; size = 8
i = 8; size = 9
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 5727K->496K(6144K)] 10709K->10630K(19968K), 0.0027462 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.01, real=0.00 secs] 
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 496K->0K(6144K)] [ParOldGen: 10134K->9942K(13824K)] 10630K->9942K(19968K), [Metaspace: 4789K->4789K(1056768K)], 0.0089587 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
i = 9; size = 10
i = 10; size = 11
i = 11; size = 12
i = 12; size = 13
i = 13; size = 14
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 5344K->2048K(6144K)] [ParOldGen: 9942K->13014K(13824K)] 15286K->15062K(19968K), [Metaspace: 4789K->4789K(1056768K)], 0.0067482 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
i = 14; size = 15
i = 15; size = 16
i = 16; size = 17
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 5230K->5120K(6144K)] [ParOldGen: 13014K->13014K(13824K)] 18244K->18134K(19968K), [Metaspace: 4789K->4789K(1056768K)], 0.0030614 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 5120K->5120K(6144K)] [ParOldGen: 13014K->12955K(13824K)] 18134K->18075K(19968K), [Metaspace: 4789K->4786K(1056768K)], 0.0093199 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid46130.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [19571071 bytes in 0.123 secs]
```

The GC is called.

Comment: Well, in your first case you have just _one_ weak reference that you're reusing and thus you're filling one list that can't get collected (or if it would get collected you'd get a reference error). Your second case uses 2 lists one of which could get collected if needed during an iteration.

Comment: If you're using two lists, then when you're adding to one, and you run out of memory, the other one can be dropped. But if there is only one list, and mid way through adding to it, you run out of memory, then the list you're currently using can't be dropped, because you're currently using it. So there is nowhere to recover memory from, and you get an out of memory error.

Comment: `holder.get()` you have a strong reference to the List to call `add` on. Before add is called, the new char[] is allocated. So you always have a strong reference when you're allocating more memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @matt. `holder.get().add(new char[_512_KB]);` cause the case.

The better code is:

```
    //-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx20m -Xms20m -XX:+PrintGCDetails
@Test(expected = OutOfMemoryError.class)
public void testOne() {
    WeakReference<List<char[]>> holder = new WeakReference<>(Lists.newLinkedList());

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        char[] chs = new char[_512_KB];
        holder.get().add(chs);
        System.out.println("i = " + i + "; size = " + holder.get().size());
    }
}
```